# Leaking toilet fill value

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, leak, toilet

The fill valve in the flush tank of one of my toilets is leaking from the top (see the green arrow in the pic below). How do I find out exactly which fill value I need to buy to replace the one I have? The red cap on the top of the value says it's a "Class Five KOHLER" valve. Is that all the info I need to find the right valve, say, on Amazon? Or, do I need some additional info such as the model number? If additional info is needed, where do I find it? Thanks.

[image: attached pic].

Comment: Kohler Genuine Part Gp1083167 Silent Fill Valve Kit For ALL Kohler Class Five Toilets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the color of the cap can vary. The distinguishing feature is the color of the shank. Your's is black so Model #GP1083167. Just replace the entire fill valve. There are some repair kits out there but most of the time , people I know end up breaking the fill valve trying to replace the parts so start fresh. You can probably get them at your home store and won't have to wait for Am........

It's a good time to check the shutoff too. If it leaks a bit when you're finished replacing the valve, just tighten up the top nut on top of it with an adjustable wrench to tighten down the packing.

Answer (score 2):

A standard valve replacement is inexpensive and easy to do as long as the shutoff valve works the valves are height adjustable and fairly universal for that kind.

Have you tried cleaning it? I have had great luck turning the water off popping the cap off putting a cup  over the valve and turning the water on, it blows the sand and scale out and then turn off reassemble the valve and turn it back on. This has repaired many toilets in Flip jobs over the years and my own and families, they usually cost under 20$ and I have a spare in the shop if it still leaks (I purchase on sale) as they are just about universal for this type.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you replace the whole fill valve, so pretty much any fill valve will work, other than weird oddball toilets that require a weird oddball fill valve.

Getting individual parts for a fill valve is enough of a pain for the average fill valve that replacing the whole thing is simpler, and cheaper if you value your time at all.